# Drop all foreign key constrain on a table in Snowflake

Tags: foreign-keys, constraints, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How do I drop all foreign-key constraints on a table in snowflake. Something like this

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME DROP ALL FOREIGN KEY
```

I don't find any script into snowflake documentation. There is single foreign key constraint drop script like this

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME DROP FOREIGN KEY(COLUMN_NAME)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible within a single SQL statement. Snowflake just guarantees that "dropping a unique/primary key with foreign key references drops all the referencing foreign keys together with the unique/primary key"

See here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constraints-drop.html

One solution for dropping more constraints may be creating a stored procedure that loops over all constraints and deletes them.

More information about creating stored procedures: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures.html

The information schema-view where you get all constraints from: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/table_constraints.html

Answer (score 0):

the structure should be as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE "RETAIL_POC"."SALES"."STORE_LOOKUP" ADD CONSTRAINT "store_pk" PRIMARY KEY (STORE_ID);

ALTER TABLE "RETAIL_POC"."SALES"."STORE_TRANSACTIONS" ADD CONSTRAINT "store_fk" FOREIGN KEY (STORE_ID) REFERENCES "RETAIL_POC"."SALES"."STORE_LOOKUP" (STORE_ID);

ALTER TABLE "RETAIL_POC"."SALES"."STORE_TRANSACTIONS" DROP CONSTRAINT "store_fk";
```

You may also drop constraints based on multiple columns:

```
ALTER TABLE "RETAIL_POC"."SALES"."STORE_TRANSACTIONS" DROP FOREIGN KEY (store_id);
```

Pertinent Documentation:
[Dopping Constraints](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constraints-drop.html)